# Answer deleted by a moderator - reconsideration?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, link-only-answers

My answer to [How to modify uitable cell color according to data in table (in Matlab)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409766/how-to-modify-uitable-cell-color-according-to-data-in-table-in-matlab) was deleted.

I believe this is an error. In my answer I provided a link to a [website article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7923610/109702) that I had just posted which directly answers the OP's question, in a very extensive manner, much more than the other posted answer to the question. The website that I referred to (UndocumentedMatlab.com) is the de-facto go-to resource for all such undocumented aspects in the Matlab language.

Such a cross-link enriches the discussion and provides readers with additional valuable information.

Comment: If it was only the link you posted, then it won't be undeleted. Link-only answers are considered to be bad. Why not add enough information into your answer so it can stand on it's own. You can then leave the link in place for additional information.

Comment: It is a combination of a link only answer and self promotion.

Comment: Oded and Dandan (and Bart) are correct.  Your best way to get it undeleted is to actually solve the user's problem in your answer, and the link should only be supplemental (plus, if it's your website, you really ought to disclose that -- the community frowns on undisclosed self-promotion).

Comment: Hehe, the blog link is dead, in itself reason enough to delete the post.  Even the assertion that it is "undocumented" is not correct.  The accepted answer was posted 6 weeks before yours.  It's on SO, it is no longer undocumented.

Comment: My article says specifically that "I just posted a dedicated article" - note that this is full disclosure. The hyperlink was simply a typo that was fixed. But I get your point -- you don't like links and you even reduce rep points for asking politely why. You think you're doing the community a favor by alienating good-standing contributors like myself? think again

Comment: @YairAltman Yes but at the moment pf deletion, your answer had these problems 1) Link-only 2) Link not working 3) Self-promotion - You could have provided an excerpt that solves the problem. Without even that, your answer is simply an advertisement of your blog. **Anybody who wants an answer, just has to click through.** This even with a disclaimer is frowned upon.

Comment: @YairAltman What exactly did you contribute in this instance? You posted a link that didn't work in October 2011, then left it until today before you fixed it. Its removal doesn't seem like a great loss personally.

Comment: *"you don't like links and you even reduce rep points for asking politely why"* surely as a good-standing contributor you have read that ["voting is somewhat different on Meta"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/whats-meta)?

Comment: I realize that a broken link is problematic. No argument there. I also understand the need for something more than a click-through link, no argument there either.

I also understand about self-promotion, but here I disagree: both the OP and Amro (the accepted answer) as well as Dang Khoa (the only other commenter on that question) referred to my code. I am the only source of knowledge on the particular aspect that was asked. So naturally when I post an expanded article about this topic (this took me some weeks to prepare, the reason for the 6-week delay) it is of direct interest to readers.

Comment: So again, I understand about all the above, but in this specific case, and in light that the entire OP's question revolved around code that I had originally posted in the CSSM newsgroup, I believe that deleting my answer does not serve the public good.

Comment: @YairAltman Then improve it based on the information you have received. Once it can stand on its own, flag it for moderator attention to have it undeleted.

Comment: I just got targeted by a mod today, so I understand your point.  It really sucks that even though a link answer gives the answer some don't like them and delete them.

Comment: Mods don't target anyone, I can tell you that for sure. Mods act on flags, which means that both yours and @LanceRoberts answer were **flagged as not an answer**. That's the only reason. Mods don't do it for fun, mods don't troll users. That's not how it works. Do not take things personally over the internet. DO ***NOT*** TAKE THINGS PERSONALLY OVER THE INTERNET. Thank you.

Answer (score 23):

Link-only answers are frowned upon because of link rot. In your case the situation was probably aggravated by it being a link to your own blog post, as this too is generally disliked by the community.

What you could have done is provided a brief summary of your blog post, along with the link and a note indicating that the blog was yours. That would've probably been acceptable.

Comment: A brief summary that directly solves the user's issue.  Posts should be able to stand on their own, without external links. If they cannot, they risk being deleted. If the moderator doesn't have too many flags to go through that day, they may leave a comment saying just what you've said.

Comment: I sense a [Reversal badge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/41/reversal) coming here! :D

Comment: I would also add that those posting link-only answers often do huge disservice to... _themselves_. Just today I've seen a [really fascinating example](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/53518/revisions "note changes in rev 2"): guy who posted a bare URL missed about **[2/3 upvotes](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rpLWS.png "question timeline shows +7 votes just for today")** they could get by simply copying a few bytes from that freakin' URL, along with losing accept to an inferior (but not link-only) answer

Answer (score -12):

There are some who don't like link answers even when they answer the question.  It's sad that they just don't get it, an answer is what's needed not their opinion of style.  They obviously haven't had enough questions in their life that needed answering.  I'm sorry they treated your answer like crap.

To appease most of those people, you'll need to put an excerpt in from where you linked to.

Comment: It's not a matter of preference, it's a matter of policy. Mods must enforce policy, even if they disagree with parts of it.  If you don't like the link-only policy I suggest you focus on getting it changed.